# Vue CDN offline usage

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, vuejs2

how can I import vue.js' CDN from the `assets` folder in the Node application? The tree of folder like

```
public
-assets
--vue.js
index.html
```

Node `public` folder setting is `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "/public")))` 
In the HTML file, I used like

```
<script src="/assets/vue.js"></script>
<script src="./assets/vue.js"></script>
<script src="../public/assets/vue.js"></script>
<script src="http://127.0.0.1:3000/public/assets/vue.js"></script>
```

I always took this errors

```
vue.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
Uncaught ReferenceError: Vue is not defined
```

The Vue app begins

```
<script>
        new Vue({
            el: '#app', ...
```

I downloaded this CDN File

```
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.14/dist/vue.js
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using a Vue CLI scaffolded project, that CDN script should be a [static asset](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#static-assets-handling) stored in `public/` instead of `src/assets`.

Move `src/assets/vue.js` to `public/vue.js`, and update the `<script>` to point there:

```html
<script src="<%= BASE_URL %>vue.js"></script>
```